# How to make the Window to be as high as the WebEngineView when the latter's size is not constrained and natural

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtwebengine

I use Qt 5.10.1 on up-to-date Windows 10 and the following simple program does not show any window:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtWebEngine 1.5

Window { id: w
    visible: true
    title: "Test"

    // with this line, the program crashes before showing anything:
    height: v.contentsSize.height

    WebEngineView { id: v
        anchors.left: w.left
        anchors.right: w.right
        anchors.top: w.top

        onContentsSizeChanged: {
            console.log(contentsSize) // no output if not both width and height properties of the web view are specified
            w.height = contentsSize.height
        }

        // if any of the following 2 lines are omitted, the web view the ":-)" string in the web view does not show up and the window looks empty although anchors.left and anchors.right are set above and the height is set
        // width: 100
        // height: 100

        // The following line crashes the program before showing the window
        // height: v.contentsSize.height

        Component.onCompleted: {
            loadHtml(":-)");
        }
    }
}
```

I specifically want the window to be as high as the web view when its size is not constrained. Relevant documentation link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#contentsSize-prop.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> // with this line, the program crashes before showing anything:
> height: v.contentsSize.height
> ```

That is because `contentsSize` is *undefined* at this point .. you haven't loaded any content yet, the qml engine crashes with *undefined* height. So just leave `Window` with no `height` .. equivalent to (`height:0`)

> I specifically want the window to be as high as the web view when its
>   size is not constrained.

Then don't `anchor` the `WebEngineView` .. that's the problem, because your anchoring - which is not complete -  will give `WebEngineView` an initial height following initial default height of `Window`, but you never change it later after loading ..  so even `Window` will not be able to resize to a smaller height!

To do that safely with minimum change, set `height`/`width` of `WebEngineView` to any value initially .. then once the contents are loaded, reset `WebEngineView` `height` / `width` to `contentsSize` .. so that`Window` can resize to that height.

```
Window { id: w
    visible: true
    title: "Test"

    WebEngineView {
        id: v
        width:1
        height:1
        onContentsSizeChanged: {
            console.log(contentsSize) // no output if not both width and height properties of the web view are specified
            //
            // here you can set web view height so that Window heigth is same as webview
            width = contentsSize.width
            height = contentsSize.height
            // and Window height
            w.height = contentsSize.height

        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            loadHtml(":-)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To make the code in the question function well, I have removed the initial height property binding of the Window, then I replaced all the anchors of WebEngineView with `anchors.fill: parent`. The advantage of your tehnique is that the user can resize the Window without the WebEngineView automatically being resized, but I can't make your tehnique work in my entire project's code (the code in the question is just a simple test case). In my project the WebEngineView is inside a Rectangle (whose size I can't set right) that is inside another Rectangle that is inside an ApplicationWindow.

Comment: @silviubogan,  One important issue to investigate: `contentsSize` is not well documented .. What I noticed is that `contentsSize` can't go to lower value than initial size of `WebEngineView` .. that's why setting `anchors` was a problem .. when you do that webview gets initial size of (160,160) from `Window` but **it will be able to grow but NOT shrink** size ! I can't make this generalization! I only observed it. Regarding your code, The point is who is the `parent` of the `WebEngineView`? in your sample code, `Window` is the parent, with different parent just take note of above observation.

Comment: I have asked another question about the fact that it won't shrink here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49719310/258462 .